# Final methods in kotlin interfaces

Tags: kotlin

As the title states, I am looking for a way to implement a final (method that cannot be overridden) in a kotlin interface.
So here is my code:

```
interface NewsItemState {

    final fun delete(newsItem: NewsItem) {
        validateCanDelete(newsItem)
        deleteNewsItem(newsItem)
    }

    fun validateCanDelete(newsItem: NewsItem)
    fun deleteNewsItem(newsItem: NewsItem)
}
```

And here is my use case:

- I want the `delete` function to be `final` so that it cannot be
  overridden in the implementations of the interface.
- I want the
  `validateCanDelete` and `deleteNewsItem` methods to be overridden in
  the implementations of the interface.

Now, I know that this is not possible at the moment and that adding final to a method is not allowed in the interface. I also know that I can achieve this by replacing the interface with an abstract class.

However, I was wondering if there is a way of implementing the same functionality in an interface because my `final` method is not going to have any "state managing" logic.

Comment: did you implemented in java? or explain more clear what is your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is to define a method/function (that is not abstract) in an interface that cannot be overridden in any of the implementations of that interface.
I haven't done it in java, as far as I know, you cannot define a final method in a java interface as well.

Comment: Its cannot be overridden in any of the implementations means what is the use of it?

Comment: The use of it is that it calls methods that are overridden in the implementations. That method will force some kind of behavior. In the example I provided, it will first call the `validateCanDelete` method (overridden in the implementation) and then calls the `deleteNewsItem` method that is also overridden in the implementation.

Comment: An `abstract class` seems like the way to go in this situation.

Comment: Make an `abstract` class that implements the `interface` and mark the method as `final`

Comment: Yes, thank you all, it looks like I am going to go with an abstract class.

Answer (score 7):

While it's not possible to have final methods in interfaces, it's absolute OK to define extension methods for interface types.

```
interface NewsItemState {
    fun validateCanDelete(newsItem: NewsItem)
    fun deleteNewsItem(newsItem: NewsItem)
}

fun NewsItemState.delete(newsItem: NewsItem) {
    validateCanDelete(newsItem)
    deleteNewsItem(newsItem)
}
```

Comment: Extension methods can be overridden in the implementation classes, so this is not satisfying my first requirement:
  "I want the delete function to be final so that it cannot be overridden in the implementations of the interface".

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski Technically, you can't override an extension method, because those are dispatched statically.  You could implement a method with the same signature it in a subclass; then any time the compiler knew it was referring to the subclass it would call that method instead of the extension.  (And _that_ method could be overridden in sub-subclasses.)  But calling it on the superclass would always give you the extension instead, so it's not a full override.

Comment: @DimitarSpasovski I'm relieved you think it clarifies things :-)